# it supposed to be a drop down list .which it's button is main .but it doesn't work.no matter how much i try the list wont be shown

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

```html
<html>
    <body>
     <button onclick="toggle()" class="nm" > main</button>
        <div class="cntnr" style="display : none;">
            <ul class="cnkid">
                <li class="cnkid"><a class="cnkid" href="delavarlogin.html">one</a></li>
                <li class="cnkid"><a class="cnkid" href="delavarsignup.html">two</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
    function toggle(){
        var x =document.getElementsByClassName('nm').nextSibling;
        if(x.style.display === 'block')
        {
            x.style.display='none';}
        else{
            x.style.display='block';
        }
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I checked the code spell correction and it is true.(i hope):|
and I guess that the script part is true too because I checked it with the src I m learning with.

Answer (score 0):

`.getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of elements, not just one element. Choose the first one from this collection (because `.nextSibling` method isn't supported with elements collection/array).

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('nm')[0].nextElementSibling;
                                             ^^^
```

Comment: I tried it but still it doesn't work.it doesnt show any thing

Comment: I've updated, use `[0].nextElementSibling`, https://jsfiddle.net/qu2owg58/